# Click event doesn't works

Tags: javascript

This Listener event doesn't work when clicked, any option. I tried "loadPage" to function() but still doesn't work.

```
//event listener
const loadPage = (id, page) => {
  $(`#${id}`).on('click', function() {
    $('#contenedor').load(page);
  });
};

// HTML generator
const generateMenuHTML = (menuData) => {
  const menuContainer = document.getElementById('contenedor');

  menuData.forEach(menuItem => {
    const { id, nombreinterno, ruta, titulo, padre } = menuItem;

    if (padre == '-1') {
      const hasChildren = menuData.some(item => item.padre == id);
      const html = menuItemTemplate(nombreinterno, titulo, hasChildren);
      menuContainer.innerHTML += html;

      if (!hasChildren) {
        loadPage(nombreinterno, ruta);
      }
    } 
  });
```

Please tell me how I can resolve this or do it in a different way. Thanks.

Edit.

The full code:

```js
    let menuData = [
        {
            "id": 257,
            "nombreinterno": "TituloMenu02",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Segundo Titulo 257",
            "padre": "-1",
            "orden": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 256,
            "nombreinterno": "TituloMenu01",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Primer Titulo 256",
            "padre": "-1",
            "orden": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": 258,
            "nombreinterno": "TituloMenu03",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Tercer Titulo 258",
            "padre": "-1",
            "orden": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": 260,
            "nombreinterno": "TituloMenu05",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Quinto Titulo 260",
            "padre": "-1",
            "orden": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": 259,
            "nombreinterno": "TituloMenu04",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Cuarto Titulo 259",
            "padre": "-1",
            "orden": "5"
        },
        {
            "id": 262,
            "nombreinterno": "MedidaList2",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Segundo Sub-Titulo 256",
            "padre": "256",
            "orden": "25610"
        },
        {
            "id": 261,
            "nombreinterno": "MedidaList",
            "ruta": "medidasListar.html",
            "titulo": "Primer Sub-Titulo 256",
            "padre": "256",
            "orden": "-1"
        },
        {
            "id": 263,
            "nombreinterno": "Submenu01",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Primer Sub-Titulo 257",
            "padre": "257",
            "orden": "-1"
        },
        {
            "id": 265,
            "nombreinterno": "Submenu01",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Primer Sub-Titulo 260",
            "padre": "260",
            "orden": "-1"
        },
        {
            "id": 264,
            "nombreinterno": "Submenu02",
            "ruta": "",
            "titulo": "Segundo Sub-Titulo 257",
            "padre": "257",
            "orden": "-1"
        }
    ];

    const menuItemTemplate = (id, title, hasChildren) => `
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="${id}" class="nav-link collapsed" href="#"${hasChildren ? ` data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${id}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse${id}"` : ''}>
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
          <span>${title}</span>
        </a>
        ${hasChildren ? `<div id="collapse${id}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${id}" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
          <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
            <!-- Contenido de los submenús -->
          </div>
        </div>` : ''}
      </li>`;

    const subMenuItemTemplate = (id, title) => `<a id="${id}" class="collapse-item" href="#">${title}</a>`;

    function loadPage(id, page) {
      $(`#${id}`).on('click', function() {
        console.log('clic-here');
        //$('#contenedor').load(page);
      });
    }

    function generateMenuHTML(menuData) {
      const menuContainer = document.getElementById('accordionSidebar');

      menuData.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.orden === '-1' && b.orden === '-1') {
          return a.titulo.localeCompare(b.titulo);
        }
        else if (a.orden === '-1') {
          return 1;
        }
        else if (b.orden === '-1') {
          return -1;
        }
        else {
          return parseInt(a.orden) - parseInt(b.orden);
        }
      });

      menuData.forEach(menuItem => {
        const { id, nombreinterno, ruta, titulo, padre } = menuItem;

        if (padre == '-1') {
          const hasChildren = menuData.some(item => item.padre == id);
          const html = menuItemTemplate(nombreinterno, titulo, hasChildren);
          menuContainer.innerHTML += html;

          if (!hasChildren) {
            loadPage(nombreinterno, ruta);
          }
        } else {
          const parentItem = menuData.find(item => item.id == padre);
          const parentCollapseId = `collapse${parentItem.nombreinterno}`;

          const parentCollapse = document.getElementById(parentCollapseId);
          const subMenuContainer = parentCollapse.querySelector('.collapse-inner');
          const html = subMenuItemTemplate(nombreinterno, titulo);
          subMenuContainer.innerHTML += html;

          loadPage(nombreinterno, ruta);
        }
      });
    }

$(function() {
  generateMenuHTML(menuData);
});
```

```css
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
    <body>
    <ul id="accordionSidebar"></ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You will see that only some options do the click event. I think if I use event inline like  in each  element can solve this, but I feel that it's the wrong way.

Comment: Are you sure `loadPage` is ever being called? In the code you've shown, it's only called inside of `generateMenuHTML` which is never called.

Comment: It is not called automatically when I click in menuItem?

Comment: No, `$('#contenedor').load(page);` is the code that would be called when you click an item because that's the code inside of the `function() {}` you pass to `.on('click', ...)`. But that click even listener is only added if you execute `loadPage`

Comment: On a sidenote: if you  need something that loads a page, use an `<a href="...">` and use CSS to style it to look however you need. Do _not_ use a `<div>` with a JS event handler. This is literally what the `a` element is for.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the problem with a element is that it recharge the website, I want show the new page in a div container called "contenedor"

Comment: @NickParsons my items come from a json and are data for the options of a menu bar. Any json is different and the elements have their own link(page), so I want to use the id attribute of each one div element for do the click event and show the link in a div container but not refresh the web like an a element.

Comment: @JorgeCardenas so are you calling `generateMenuHTML`. Might be useful if you can create a [mre]

Comment: @NickParsons how I do that? other way for do that I want can be use the event online onclick="", but is it right?. Thanks for all.

Comment: To call generateHTML you need to do `generateMenuHTML(menuData)` which I’m guessing you’re doing somewhere right?

Comment: @NickParsons I do a minimal reproducible example of this, please check the edit part

Comment: @JorgeCardenas You need to use event delegation, as the elements are being added to the DOM later on (currently when you add your even listeners the elements don't exist yet). To do that you can use ```$(document).on('click', `#${id}`, function() {```

Comment: @NickParsons THANK YOU! That line resolved all. +1 for you haha